# WinJs Settings panel close

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs

I can use the SettingsFlyout afterhide event to know when one of my settings pages closes, but how can I detect when the overall Settings page closes. i.e. the user goes back to the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the user returns to the app. If they click outside of the settings UI while your settings page is displayed, then the afterhide event will fire. But if the user is displaying the main settings page, that's UI that is controlled by the OS, and isn't really part of your app, per se. For example, the user could open the settings UI to change the system volume, or make changes to network settings. In those circumstances, it wouldn't really be appropriate for your app to receive notifications.

So I don't think there is an event to subscribe to for the main settings pane closing. As such, you should subscribe to afterhide on each of your settings pages to ensure that you can capture any changes appropriately.

Hope that helps.

For more info on Windows Store app development, register for [Generation App](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).

Comment: Thanks. It was the general page close event I was after, but if it doesn't exist, I'll continue using the afterhide event on my own pages.